# How to facilitate communication between php script on a server to a running Java application on another server?

Tags: java, php, communication

How to establish a way for Java application to listen to data being sent by php ? Sockets or Http POST ?

Essentially, I have Java application running on another server waiting for certain string data sent by PHP script running on other server.

Any library suggestions or example codes will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably going to be to set up a java servlet "container" (server), such as tomcat (you can pay a lot of money for something else, if you have to for corporate reasons).

http://tomcat.apache.org/

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader()
or
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream()

Be aware there is a bit of work up front, just to set up and host "hello.jsp", but adding the mapping for the "myservice" servlet in web.xml is not *too* bad.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest implementing a REST api. If you can't or don't want to, using sockets is the most secure way...

If you are sending FROM php, I recommend using a RESTful API with authentication. Send JSON data, get JSON data back. It allows for better future expansion too.