# Java: how to listen for http POST request sent by php?

Tags: java, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to facilitate communication between php script on a server to a running Java application on another server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551113/how-to-facilitate-communication-between-php-script-on-a-server-to-a-running-java)

I have a php script that will send POST request containing string data to a Java application I wrote running on another server.

How do I make my Java application accept POST and read the string data ? I want Java application to listen for incoming string data sent via POST and, as soon as the string data is received, it will process the string data.

What library is used ?

OR Is it better to use sockets ? how would I accomplish the above ?

Comment: Honestly!? YOU JUST POSTED THIS SAME QUESTION! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551113/how-to-facilitate-communication-between-php-script-on-a-server-to-a-running-java/4551123#4551123 - please don't waste people's time and try to cheat the system by asking the same question to appear at the top of the list

Comment: this isn't the same question, and your answer was not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See other question:  short answer is "Tomcat"